# Changing chart column color based off data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a python script that parses a csv file and creates a mixed chart from it.

If the Current Progress has dropped since the Previous Progress by more than 5, I would like to change the color of the CurrentProg bar to red. Is it possible to do this?

For example, the table below is a sample of the csv file that I am parsing. I would like CurrentProg bar for Derick and Lisa to be red as shown in the graph below it.

> Name                 OldProg                  PrevProg                    CurrentProg              Goal
>   Derick                     45                                     60                                      52                         90
>   Jenna                           56                                     87                                      89                         90
>   Lisa                      78                                     93                                      76                         90
>   Harry                    98                                    84                                      79                         90

[image]

Here is a snippet of the code that parses the csv file and puts them into a bars/lines for the chart.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
names = df['name'].values
x = np.arange(len(names))*2
w = 0.40
plt.bar(x-w, df['Old Progress'].values, width=w*0.7, label='OldProg', color = "cyan")
plt.bar(x, df['Previous Progress'].values, width=w*0.7, label='PrevProg', color = "green")
plt.bar(x+w, df['Current Progress'].values, width=w*0.7, label='CurrentProg', color = "blue")
plt.plot(x, df['Goal'].values, lw=2, label='Goal', color = "red")
```

Please let me know if I need to clarify anything further. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.bar()` can accept a list of colors with the same length as the number of items in the bar plot, rather than just a single color.

Thus, you can calculate the colors for each element in the bar plot, and pass that as the `colors` parameter.

Something like this shoould do the trick:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
progress_difference = df['CurrentProg'] - df['PrevProg']
colors = ['Red' if d < -5 else 'Grey' for d in progress_difference]
...
plt.bar(x+w, df['CurrentProg'].values, width=w*0.7, 
        label='CurrentProg', color = colors)
```